# What type of accessToken scope/resourceType do I need when using Pnp-Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

In the PNP Docs it shows:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#example-13

you can access the resource with an Oauth2 AccessToken:
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -AccessToken $token`

When I try to get the access token via the Az Cli in powershell...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token

```
$token=az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query accessToken 
$token=$token.Trim('"')

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://mysharepointdomain.com/sites/SiteINeedToAccess -AccessToken $token

Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin                                                                        
Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

When I use the alternate Connect-PnPOnline method using a pfx certificate with password, I can access the resources fine.

Is there another type of access-token I should be requesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned ***"Connect-PnPOnline method using a pfx certificate with password"*** is working fine.
Please check whether you have assigned required **permissions** and **scopes** while generating the access token via Azure CLI.

**To validate the scopes,** make use of [**JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io**](https://jwt.io/) website to decode the token.

[image]

If **`scp`** attribute doesn't include **SharePoint online permissions** like: **`Sites.FullControl.All`**, **`Sites.ReadWrite.All`** etc., then this might lead to ***`401`** unauthorized error*.

Make sure to grant the **[permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)** like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Your app -> API permissions -> Add permissions -> SharePoint***

[image]

For more information, please **refer** below links if helpful:

[Azure app cannot access SharePoint v1 API - 401 unauthorized access error - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/131535/azure-app-cannot-access-sharepoint-online-sites-us.html?msclkid=3403f63cd09a11ec97e20833e1dd555e)

[pnp powershell - PnP Cmdlets / Provisioning: What are the minimal required permissions for basic SharePoint operations? - SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297050/pnp-cmdlets-provisioning-what-are-the-minimal-required-permissions-for-basic)

##### UPDATE:

As mentioned by you in the comment, please note that **`Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin`** also uses **legacy CSOM** that has limitation which we can't change even **`Sites.FullControl.All`** permission is granted. To avoid that, continue using pfx certificate with password for `Connect-PnPOnline` method as a workaround !

**Reference:** https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/305

Comment: I Stumbled upon this github issue: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/305#issuecomment-782015181 ... I think it may be impossible right now due to it wanting the legacy CSOM API

Comment: Thanks for the comment, updated the answer to help other community members !